Adding empty rows between values while using Filter or Sort
Hi I am wondering if I can add empty values to filter or sort formulas in excel.
My idea is to create an empty row to separate the results.
So for instance, this is a result of a sort function:

I would like to separate the "one's" and the "two's" with a row between them.
I know I can do this with two sorts, however the information is dynamic.
Would also love to know if the excel Filter function would have a similar feature.
=SORT(data!A:D,4)

Expected result:


Please share the sort formula. Also, mock up some sample data as text so we have something to work with. Finally, show us the expected result. BTW, no feature in any Excel function can do what you're asking. You'll have to use several Excel functions.

Insert Rows Between Group Members
=LET(data,A2:B11,group_col,1,insert_rows,1,e_val,"",
    d,IF(data="","",data),
    e,EXPAND(e_val,insert_rows,COLUMNS(d),e_val),
    g,CHOOSECOLS(data,group_col),
    u,UNIQUE(g),
    first,FILTER(d,g=TAKE(u,1)),
    r,REDUCE(first,DROP(u,1),LAMBDA(rr,r,
        VSTACK(rr,e,FILTER(d,g=r)))),
    r)



In your particular case, you could use
=LET(data,SORT(data!A2:D11,4),group_col,4,...

adjusting the last row. You cannot use entire columns.

Or you could implement the sort within d:
... d,SORT(IF(data="","",data),group_col),...




I used the formula you gave me:
=LET(data,SORT(data!A2:D400,4),group_col,4,insert_rows,1,e_val,"",
d,IF(data="","",data),
e,EXPAND(e_val,insert_rows,COLUMNS(d),e_val),
g,CHOOSECOLS(data,group_col),
u,UNIQUE(g),
first,FILTER(d,g=TAKE(u,1)),
r,REDUCE(first,DROP(u,1),LAMBDA(rr,r, VSTACK(rr,e,FILTER(,g=r)))),r)
But I get #Value.
If I click on the fx button and scroll through the formula, the line "IF(data="","",data)," returns #Name.
Cheers for the help.

Try to replace the three occurrences of data with e.g. array since your sheet is named data.

@VBasic2008
Still have the same issue when change data for array or another word.
Found out it is also giving the same issue at "EXPAND(e_val,insert_rows,COLUMNS(d),e_val)"

You lost the d in FILTER(,g=r): it has to be FILTER(d,g=r).

@VBasic2008 Ah I spot it now. I get values from it however the whole data shows "staff" instead of the values. (the name I gave)
=LET(staff,SORT(data!A2:D397,4),group_col,4,insert_rows,1,e_val,"",
d,IF(staff="","","staff"),
e,EXPAND(e_val,insert_rows,COLUMNS(d),e_val),
g,CHOOSECOLS(staff,group_col),
u,UNIQUE(g),
first,FILTER(d,g=TAKE(u,1)),
r,REDUCE(first,DROP(u,1),LAMBDA(rr,r, VSTACK(rr,e,FILTER(d,g=r)))),r)

Come on, you can do better. It has to be d,IF(staff="","",staff),. staff is a variable, not a string.

I am going to study every line of this let formula. it is working. thank you so much!

Here's a hint. Look at the bottommost r. It is returning the result of the REDUCE. You can replace it with any other variable to see what it produces. Note that the r inside the REDUCE has nothing to do with the bottommost r (or the r to the left of REDUCE ). They are two different variables.

Another way of doing this, if you have some data that you need to sort, is to add the blank rows as part of the sorting process:
=LET(data,A2:B9,
group,TAKE(data,,-1),
uniques,UNIQUE(group),
SORTBY(EXPAND(data,ROWS(data)+ROWS(uniques),,""),VSTACK(group,uniques+0.5)))



Here is another alternative formula, this assumes there is no Excel Constraints as per the tags posted per OP:


• Formula used in cell D1
=LET(
     _array, A2:B11,
     REDUCE(A1:B1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_array)), LAMBDA(r,c,
     LET(a, INDEX(_array,c,), b,  IFERROR(IF(INDEX(_array,c,2)=INDEX(_array,c+1,2), a,
     EXPAND(a,2,,"")),a), VSTACK(r,IF(b=0,"",b))))))



I tried your solution and got values, however it added a row to every single line

@Believe82 not sure what you are saying, screenshot above shows single line is added after each groups. Can you show us a screenshot why it is not working for you. looking forward to it

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wTmpJ_3yffvu1o8g13LhvGhfm_BnZeNw/view?usp=sharing
Here is what I meant.
And the code:
=LET(
_array, SORT(data!A2:D400,4),
REDUCE(A1:B1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_array)), LAMBDA(r,c,
LET(a, INDEX(_array,c,), b,  IFERROR(IF(INDEX(_array,c,2)=INDEX(_array,c+1,2), a,
EXPAND(a,2,,"")),a), VSTACK(r,IF(b=0,"",b))))))
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XvULVFJFgm9FM3yG-2DsuHF0nL_nquSD/view?usp=drive_link

@Believe82 there is no access.

sorry I made it wrong. Should have full access now.

@Believe82 that does nt help anything thanks.

Using TOCOL and CHOOSEROWS
(Thanks to JvdV)
=LAMBDA(values_to_group_by, data, group_header,
    LET(
        next, DROP(values_to_group_by, 1),
        indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(values_to_group_by)),
        group_header_index, MAX(indices) + 1,
        indices_with_header, TOCOL(
            HSTACK(
                indices,
                IF(
                    values_to_group_by <> next,
                    group_header_index,
                    NA()
                )
            ),
            2
        ),
        data, IF(ISBLANK(data), "", data),
        result, CHOOSEROWS(
            VSTACK(data, group_header),
            indices_with_header
        ),
        result
    )
)(TAKE(_data, , -1), _data, HSTACK("", ""))

With _data =Sheet1!$A$1:$B$11:



Adopting Tom's:
=LAMBDA(values_to_group_by, data, group_header,
    LET(
        sorted, SORTBY(data, values_to_group_by),
        data, IF(ISBLANK(sorted), "", sorted),
        values_to_group_by, SORT(values_to_group_by),
        next, DROP(values_to_group_by, 1),
        indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(values_to_group_by)),
        group_header_index, MAX(indices) + 1,
        indices_with_header, TOCOL(HSTACK(indices, IF(values_to_group_by <> next, group_header_index, NA())), 2),
        result, CHOOSEROWS(VSTACK(data, group_header), indices_with_header),
        result
    )
)(TAKE(data_tom, , -1), data_tom, HSTACK("", ""))


